# SQLSTATE[42S02] Problem with artisan tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate, artisan-migrate, tinker

I have a problem with artisan tinker
Problem:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `projects` (`title`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My first Project, bla bla, 2020-12-18 14:21:42, 2020-12-18 14:21:42))'
```

my migration file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;     
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class BusinessTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Выполнение миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('mail');
    $table->string('web-site');
    $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
    * Отмена миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
    Schema::drop('business');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the correct data set in your `.env` file? Did you run the migrations with `php artisan migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem dosent do anything with Business Migration.

how ever your business migration should be :

```
Schema::create('business',
```

not `flights` .
its about Project Table.

you have to create a project migration:

```
php artisan make:migration projects_table
```

and populate with required fields:

```
class ProjectsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Выполнение миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
    * Отмена миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
    Schema::drop('projects');
    }
}
```